# Aggregate function to detect trend in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, aggregate-functions

I'm using a psql DB to store a data structure like so:

```
datapoint(userId, rank, timestamp)
```

where timestamp is the Unix Epoch milliseconds timestamp.

In this structure I store the rank of each user each day, so it's like:

```
UserId   Rank  Timestamp
1        1     1435366459
1        2     1435366458
1        3     1435366457
2        8     1435366456
2        6     1435366455
2        7     1435366454
```

So, in the sample data above, userId 1 its improving it's rank with each measurement, which means it has a positive trend, while userId 2 is dropping in rank, which means it has a negative trend.

What I need to do is to detect all users that have a positive trend based on the last N measurements.

Comment: I think this is an algorithm question. I think this could help: average rank over your last datapoints and compare whether the last rank is greater or less than that.

Comment: What exactly is a positive trend in your terms? Do you require that each rank R_n+1 is strictly smaller than its predecessor R_n ? Or is it sufficient if each one is not larger than its predecessor? Or is it sufficent that rank R_n+N is smaller than R_n (ignoring the intermediate values) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach would be to perform a linear regression on the each user's rank, and check if the slope is positive or negative. Luckily, PostgreSQL has a builtin function to do that - `regr_slope`:

```
SELECT   user_id, regr_slope (rank1, timestamp1) AS slope
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

This query gives you the basic functionality. Now, you can dress it up a bit with `case` expressions if you like:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       CASE WHEN slope > 0 THEN 'positive' 
            WHEN slope < 0 THEN 'negative' 
            ELSE 'steady' END AS trend
FROM   (SELECT   user_id, regr_slope (rank1, timestamp1) AS slope
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY user_id) t
```

**Edit:**
Unfortunately, `regr_slope` doesn't have a built in way to handle "top N" type requirements, so this should be handled separately, e.g., by a subquery with `row_number`:

```
-- Decoration outer query
SELECT user_id, 
       CASE WHEN slope > 0 THEN 'positive' 
            WHEN slope < 0 THEN 'negative' 
            ELSE 'steady' END AS trend
FROM   (-- Inner query to calculate the slope
        SELECT   user_id, regr_slope (rank1, timestamp1) AS slope
        FROM     (-- Inner query to get top N
                  SELECT user_id, rank1, 
                         ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                                           ORDER BY timestamp1 DESC) AS rn
                  FROM   my_table) t
        WHERE    rn <= N -- Replace N with the number of rows you need
        GROUP BY user_id) t2
```

Comment: I tried your query in a SQL Fiddle, but it always returns NULL for the slope. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/924fd/2

Comment: thanks! looks like an elegant and easy solution, but i tried it on my testcase, and even the trend is clearely positive, the slope is smaller than 0

Comment: It works if you switch `rank` and `timestamp`. Maybe some rounding error? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/924fd/27/0 Although this takes all rows into account, not only the last `n`.

Comment: Indeed, seems to be some rounding issue - with smaller values it seems to work.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to extend your query to only respect the last `n` rows? I would vote for it then. Seems elegant to me.

Comment: @GhostGambler you'd probably need another level of inner query with an analytical function. I edit my answer and added an example.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik ! Great stuff here! Is there a way to also calculate the delta ? delta = the N rank - the current rank

Comment: @maephisto The `first_value` function should do the trick, but let's follow [so]'s guidelines and keep it one topic per post and discuss this issue in its own thread?

Comment: @Mureinik Indeed, thank you! I managed to achieved the delta calculation based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use analytic functions for this. Overall approach:

- compute the previous rank using lag()
- use case to decide whether the trend is positive or not (0 or 1)
- use min() to get the minimum trend over the preceding N rows; if the trend was positive for N rows, this returns 1, otherwise 0. To limit it to N rows, use the `between N preceding and 0 following` clause of the windowing function

Code:

```
select v2.*,
  min(positive_trend) over (partition by userid order by timestamp1
                             rows between 3 preceding and 0 following) as trend_overall
from (
  select v1.*,
    (case when prev_rank < rank1 then 0 else 1 end) as positive_trend
  from (
    select userid,
      rank1,
      timestamp1,
      lag(rank1) over (partition by userid order by timestamp1) as prev_rank
    from t1
    order by userid, timestamp1
  ) v1
) v2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d207/3)

**UPDATE**

To only get the userid with the overall trend and the delta for the rank, you'll have to add another call to `lag(.., N+1)` to get the nth previous rank and `row_number()` to get a numbering within the same userid:

```
select v3.userid, v3.trend_overall, delta_rank
from (  
  select v2.*,
    min(positive_trend) over (partition by userid order by timestamp1
                               rows between 3 preceding and 0 following) as trend_overall,
    latest_rank - prev_N_rank as delta_rank
  from (
    select v1.*,
      (case when prev_rank < rank1 then 0 else 1 end) as positive_trend,
      max(case when v1.rn = 1 then rank1 else NULL end) over (partition by userid) as latest_rank
    from (
      select userid,
        rank1,
        timestamp1,
        lag(rank1) over (partition by userid order by timestamp1) as prev_rank,
        lag(rank1, 4) over (partition by userid order by timestamp1) as prev_N_rank,
        row_number() over (partition by userid order by timestamp1 desc) as rn
      from t1
      order by userid, timestamp1
    ) v1
  ) v2
) v3 
where rn = 1
group by userid, trend_overall, delta_rank
order by userid, trend_overall, delta_rank
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d207/9)

Comment: thanks @Frank! This indeed is very close of what i'm looking. One thing though, is it possible to aggregate the result in such way that it returns only one row per userId, the trend(1/0) and the delta (the N rank - the current rank) ?