# Time Series in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, amazon-redshift

I have a huge database of eCommerce transactions on Redshift, running into about 900 million rows, with the headers being somewhat similar to this.

```
 id | date_stamp | location | item   | amount
001 | 2009-12-28 | A1       | Apples | 2
002 | 2009-12-28 | A2       | Juice  | 2
003 | 2009-12-28 | A1       | Apples | 1
004 | 2009-12-28 | A4       | Apples | 2
005 | 2009-12-29 | A1       | Juice  | 6
006 | 2009-12-29 | A4       | Apples | 2
007 | 2009-12-29 | A1       | Water  | 7
008 | 2009-12-28 | B7       | Juice  | 14
```

Is it possible to find trends within items? For example, if I wanted to see how "Apples" performed in terms of sales, between 2009-12-28 and 2011-12-28, at location A4, how would I go about it? Ideally I would like to generate a table with positive/negative trending, somewhat similar to the post here - 
[Aggregate function to detect trend in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039054/aggregate-function-to-detect-trend-in-postgresql)
I have performed similar analysis on small data sets in R, and even visualizing it using ggplot isn't a big challenge, but the sheer size of the database is causing me some troubles, and extremely long querying times as well. 
For example,

```
select * 
from fruitstore.sales
where item = 'Apple' and location = 'A1'
order by date_stamp
limit 1000000;
```

takes about 2500 seconds to execute, and times out often. 
I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: whay do you exactly mean by `how "Apples" fared between 2009-12-28 and 2011-12-28, at location A4`?

Comment: Show us your query, what result are you expecting and how long is taking. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Sorry, I will just edit it to make the question more clear. I meant, how "apples" performed in terms of sales per day.

Comment: `select * ` can you elaborate what do you expect the resultset to show? Is it a period aggregation, SUM(amount) GROUP BY month, is it something else?

Answer (score 4):

900M rows is quite a bit for stock Postgres to handle. One of the MPP variants (like Citus) would be able to handle it better.

Another option is to change how you're storing the data. A far more efficient structure would be to have 1 row for each month/item/location, and store an int array of amounts. That would cut things down to ~300M rows, which is much more manageable. I suspect most of your analysis tools will want to see the data as an array anyway.

Comment: OP states that the data is in Redshift

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [window functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html). They're great for this type of use case. They were a bit tough for me to get my head around but can save you some serious contortions with SQL.

This will show you how many apples were sold per day for the period you're interested in:

```
select date_trunc('day', date_stamp) as day, count(*) as sold
from fruitstore.sales
where item = 'Apple' and location = 'A4'
    and date_stamp::date >= '2009-12-28'::date and date_stamp::date <= '2011-12-28'::date
group by 1 order by 1 asc
```

Regarding performance, avoid using `select *` in Redshift. It's a columnar store where data for different columns is spread across nodes. Being explicit about the columns and only referencing the ones you use will save Redshift from moving a lot of unneeded data over the network.

Make sure you're picking good [distkey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-best-dist-key.html) and [sortkeys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html) for your tables. In a time series table the timestamp should definitely be one of the sortkeys. Enabling compression on your tables can help too.

Schedule regular VACUUM and ANALYZE runs on your tables.

Also if there's any way to restrict the range of data you're looking at by filtering possible records out in the where clause, it can help a lot. For example, if you know you only care about the trend for the last few days it can make a huge difference to limit on time like:

```
where date_stamp >= sysdate::date - '5 day'::interval
```

Here's a [good article](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx31034QG0G3ED1/Top-10-Performance-Tuning-Techniques-for-Amazon-Redshift) with performance tips.

Answer (score 0):

To filter results in your SQL query, you can use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
     item='Apple' AND
     date_stamp BETWEEN '2009-12-28' AND '2011-12-28' AND
     location = 'A4'
```

Using Aggregate functions, you can summarize fruit sales between two dates at a location, for instance:

```
SELECT item as "fruit", sum(amount) as "total"
FROM myTable
WHERE     
     date_stamp BETWEEN '2009-12-28' AND '2011-12-28' AND
     location = 'A4'
GROUP BY item
```

Your question asking how `apples` "Fared" isn't terrible descriptive, but using a `WHERE` clause and aggregate functions (don't forget your group by) are probably where you need to aim.